# Como apagar arquivos em um diretório com script batch?

Tags: windows, batch

Preciso que ao executar um *script.cmd* ele apague todos os arquivos com as seguintes extensões: `.txt` e `.mp4` se existirem. Esses arquivos estão localizados na seguinte pasta `C:\comando\batch\diretorio\teste` e o *script.cmd* está localizado em `C:\comando\batch`.

Como eu poderia fazer isso, sabendo que depois destes comandos, outros irão ser executados, mas não para a pasta *teste*, e sim na pasta *batch*.

Ou seja, é possível fazer isso sem sair da pasta *batch*?

Os comandos precisam ser compatíveis com o Windows 2003/XP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É possível sim. 
Para deletar os arquivos, use o [`del`](http://ss64.com/nt/del.html).

Se preferir deletar os arquivos usando o caminho absoluto, use a variável `%~dp0` para obter a pasta do *script* e indique a subpasta alvo.

Você pode iterar sobre um `array` com as extensões e usar o [coringa](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html) para corresponder à arquivos com certas extensões.

```
@echo off

set "subpasta=%~dp0%diretorio\teste\" REM a pasta do batch e subpasta
set "extensoes=txt mp4"               REM separe as extensoes com espaco

for %%i in (%extensoes%) do (
    echo Deletando arquivos do tipo %%i da pasta %subpasta%
    del %subpasta%*.%%i
)

if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (
    echo Operacao realizada com sucesso
) else (
    echo Nao foi possivel deletar um ou mais arquivos
)
```

<sub>**Obs:** Para não mostrar nenhuma saída, você redirecionar o [*stdout* e *stderr*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluxos_padr%C3%A3o) para `null` assim: `del %subpasta%*.%%i 2> nul`</sub>

Comment: Só uma duvida, da forma como está aí, não é necessário nenhuma confirmação ao executar o `del` né? Ou tem de colocar o `/q` como mencionado nos comentários? Se sim, como seria? ps: gostei do comando `%~dp0` muito interessante :)

Comment: @Florida Até onde sei não, mas se você quiser pode usar o `/p` para perguntar antes. Sobre o `%~dp0`, nesse link tem outros também: https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 3):

Como é uma sub pasta do seu diretorio raiz, não a necessidade de sair, mas eu em particular prefiro sempre usar o comando com um path absoluto para maior segurança.

`del C:\comando\batch\diretorio\teste\*.txt /s`

`del C:\comando\batch\diretorio\teste\*.mp4 /s`

O '/s' apaga recursivamente.

ex.: dentro da pasta tiver outra pasta(teste/videos)com arquivos mp4, eles tambem seram apagados.

Dai você pode continuar com suas rotinas!

Comment: Eu acho que `/s` é para deletar os arquivos de como recursivo, [veja aqui](http://ss64.com/nt/del.html). Para ignorar as perguntas, deve ser `/q`.

Comment: É isso mesmo @stderr , obrigado pela observação.